# Anyway to get the autoresized frame of an UIVIew?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, autoresizingmask, viewdidappear

I have an UIButton that is set to autoresize depending the partent view (iPhone 5 4inch screen). I have a border image that I show around the button once it is selected. The problem is that the UIButton frame returns the original size even when it is autoresized and so I cannot set the frame of the border image to match it.

Is there a way to get the frame after autoresize is fone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried UIViewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? It's not as fine-grained as `layoutSubviews`, which is for individual views, but it might still be sufficient depending on your needs.

Comment: I did try that. But it doesnt return the autosized frame of the view. viewDidLayoutSubviews is called before viewDidAppear. But viewDidAppear does not return the autosized frame either

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to place this logic in the layoutSubviews method of your UIView.  This will get called right after the view has finished autoresizing.

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
   [super layoutSubviews];

   //Logic to layout your custom views would go at this point, i.e.

   CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectInset([self bounds], 0, 0);
   [[self button] setFrame:buttonFrame];      
}
```

Comment: layoutSubviews is a UIView method right? I would probably have to subclass UIButton?

Comment: its a UIViewController method.  this method should go in the viewController containing the UIButton (and even letting you wire it up in storyboard/XIB).  In my example, I have the UIButton set as a instance variable of the viewController.  I don't see  why you'd have to subclass UIButton.

Comment: I think you got it wrong. It's actually a UIView method. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html. So I guess I would have to subclass UIButton.

Comment: You're right - I got confused with viewDidLayoutSubviews.  I'll update my answer.